# Get substrings of a specific format

Tags: arrays, regex, string, go, split

I have a string in this format:

```
2002:4 2003:"\x02\x00\x04\x01" 2004:"\x00\x06\x03" 2005:1 2006:"YYYY-MM-DD" 3000:"Date time" 3001:"01/01/1900" 3002:"07/20/2020"
```

I am only interested in the values `3000:"Date time", 3001: "01/01/1900", 3002:"07/20/2020"` - the ones above 3000. Initially, I tried splitting the string at spaces for a different example. But here, "Date time" also has a space in it. So my logic breaks in this case. I'm new to Golang so I want to know what is the best way to do this in Go? Can I try using Regex or is it a bad idea?

Comment: Can you please some code that you tried?

Comment: Are there any assumptions you can make about this? Do you know if the character `"` could appear within the string?

Comment: @HamzaAnis I tried this: fieldOptions := strings.Split(option, " ")
Anyway, I tried regex and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string in quotes after `3000:` never contains other double-quote characters `"`, you can use a regex like the following:

`30\d+:".*?"`

A more complete Go snippet (adapt according to your actual needs):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

const s = `2002:4 2003:"\x02\x00\x04\x01" 2004:"\x00\x06\x03" 2005:1 2006:"YYYY-MM-DD" 3000:"Date time" 3001:"01/01/1900" 3002:"07/20/2020"
`

func main() {

    re, err := regexp.Compile(`30\d+:".*?"`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    matches := re.FindAllString(s, -1)
    fmt.Println(matches) // [3000:"Date time" 3001:"01/01/1900" 3002:"07/20/2020"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I mean you could write a super simple parser:

https://play.golang.org/p/q0oeNlhSKJT

```
func parse(s string) {
    tokens := make(map[string]string)
    key := []byte{}
    value := []byte{}
    inQuote := false
    inKey := true
    for  i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        ch := s[i]
        // If we see a :, we're switching from key to value (or vice versa)
        // unless we're inside of a quote
        if ch == ':' && !inQuote {
            inKey = !inKey
        // if we see a ", we're switching from in a quote to out or out to in
        } else if ch == '"' {
            inQuote = !inQuote
        // if we see a space, and we're not in a quote, we've completed a key value pair
        } else if ch == ' ' && !inQuote {
            inKey = !inKey
            if inKey {
                tokens[string(key)] = string(value)
                key = []byte{}
                value = []byte{}
            }
        // otherwise, add this character to either they key or the value
        } else if inKey {
            key = append(key, ch)
        } else {
            value = append(value, ch)
        }
    }
    // add the final key value pair
    tokens[string(key)] = string(value)
    // print out the ones with keys >= 3000
    for k, v := range tokens {
        n, _ := strconv.Atoi(k)
        if (n >= 3000) {
            fmt.Println("K: " + k + " | V: " + v)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this solution works. I implemented using regex from the comments.